# Are pancharatra agamas followed outside the South (not counting Southern transplants)?

Tags: agamas

I am not even sure temples outside the South not run by Southern transplants follow ANY agamas.

Comment: Not only Pancharatra agamas, Shaiva agamas are also not followed in some temples in North India. As far as I know, according to some Shaiva agamas, only priest can touch Shiva lingam. But in north, Shiva lingam is touched by all.